# How to compare two nsarrays with different values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Hi i have two nsarrays.

Array A:

```
 arrProductSelection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"English",@"German",@"Russian",@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",nil];
```

Array B:

```
arrProductSelectionB = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"deselcted",@"selected",@"selected",@"selected",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",nil];
```

I need to compare two arrays and get the value from array A by comparing with array B having value as selected. That is i should get german,chinese and russian sepearted by comma as nsstring.

Comment: is count of both array same?

Comment: You should use dictionary for this purpose.

Comment: yes they are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *arrProductSelection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"English",@"German",@"Russian",@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",@"French",nil];

NSArray *arrProductSelectionB = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"deselcted",@"selected",@"selected",@"selected",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",@"deselcted",nil];

for(int i = 0; i< arrProductSelectionB.count-1;i ++) {
    if ([arrProductSelectionB[i] isEqualToString:@"selected"]) {
        [arrSelected addObject:arrProductSelection[i]];
    }
}

NSString *strSelected = [arrSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"%@", strSelected);//output: German,Russian,Chinese
```

Comment: Green tick for you soon

Answer (score 0):

first i would make sure both arrays have same counters for safety something like

```
if (arrProductSelection.count == arrProductSelectionB) {

//than all you need is one for cycle something like  :

    for (int i = 0; i < arrProductionSelectionB.count; i++) {
         if ([arrProductionSelectionB[i] isEqualToString: @"selected"]) {
         do something magically with arrProductSelection[i];
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make this type of array then manage easly.

```
(
        {
        flag = deselcted;
        name = English;
    },
        {
        flag = selected;
        name = German;
    },
        {
        flag = deselcted;
        name = Russian;
    },
        {
        flag = deselcted;
        name = Chinese;
    }
)
```

==> Array[(dictionary),(dictionary),.....]

Answer (score 0):

if you need result in an array, Here is the function:

```
NSMutableArray*resultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i<arrProductSelectionB.count;i++){
        if ([[arrProductSelectionB objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@"selected"]) {
            [resultArray addObject:[arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
```

resultArrayhave the values which you need.